# How does a VM in “bridged” mode get its traffic back when it has to go through an adapter of different IP address?

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Let's say a virtual machine is connected to the network via a virtual adapter created by host's Virtualbox. Also here are the IP addresses:

192.168.1.1 Gateway

192.168.1.2 Host machine running Virtualbox

192.168.1.3 Virtual Machine inside Virtualbox

192.168.1.3/VM sends out a packet to start a handshake (Step 1) with some far away web server on the Internet. It has to go through the host machine's physical adapter. (Step 2) The packet from the other end comes back. How does the gateway know to send it to the host machine even if the host machine has a different ip? How does the host machine's network card know to "intercept" the packet and send it off to the guest VM?

It's like you want to send a message to Alice (the VM), but Alice is "behind" Bob (host machine running Virtualbox "virtualizing" Alice) so do you send it to Bob and trust him to send it to Alice or what do you do (as a gateway)? Everything that reaches Alice must go through Bob right?

My guess is that the router has a routing table and it knows that 192.168.1.2 and .3 are on the same interface (same physical port on the router's ports I assume) and it sends it off there. From there, the NIC card on the host machine (which works at layer-2 so it ignores the IP address) looks at the MAC addresses of the packet and just knows to send it off to the virtual host.

Again, I hope this makes sense! Apologizes if it doesn't. I'll clarify on anything. I admit my networking knowledge is a bit rusty. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bridged mode, the hosts act like a bridge. That means the virtual machine has its own layer 2 hardware address.

Packets from the virtual machine that need to be sent on the physical network are sourced from the virtual machine's hardware address. Packets sent on the physical network to the virtual machine will be sent to the virtual machine's hardware address. If there are no firewalls preventing this, protocols over Ethernet other than TCP/IP should work since all the bridging takes place at layer 2.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this as the answer. To add onto this, a bridge basically creates a switch (virtually). So you would have the host OS be attached to a "physical" port on to one switch. Guest VM be attached to another. Router/Gateway knows to send packets down that one physical port that now has two IP's so it'll go that way. Going back to my analogy. Bob would "side step"  out of the way and create a "fork in the road" so Alice can receive her mail without Bob having to intercept it.